CSS auto change li width when label text increases
I have some problems with this CSS.

How can I make each li's size increases or decreases according to the label's size?
Also, when the li run to the end of the page's width, how can I make it wrap to a new row?


For example:

Black's width should be smaller
Forest Green's width should be wider
The first row should end at Purple, that's the width of the page. Rose Pink, Rose Red.. and the rest, should wrap to a new row



.cable-config span {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #86939E;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cable-choose {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 25px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.cable-choose {
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.cable-choose li {
    /* float: left; */
    margin: 15px 5px 0 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.cable-choose label,
.cable-choose input {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 0; */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.cable-choose input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0.01;
    z-index: 100;
}

.cable-choose input[type="radio"]:checked+label,
.Checked+label {
    background: yellow;  
}

.cable-choose label {
    border: 2px solid #E1E8EE;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 90;
}

.cable-choose .sold-out {
    color: #ced3d9;
}

.radio-custom:checked ~ label {
    border: 2px solid #121b21;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
<div class="cable-config clearfix">
  <div><h5>Color:</h5></div>

  <ul class="cable-choose">
    <li>
      <input
        type="radio"
      /><span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span
      ><label class="" for="black">Black</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input
        type="radio"
      /><span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span
      ><label class="" for="forest-green">Forest Green</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input
        type="radio"
        disabled=""
      /><span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span
      ><label class="sold-out" for="light-purple">Light Purple</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




Consider using flexbox, it makes things really easy.

I am not very good in CSS. Can you help me please?

"How can I make each li's size increases or decreases according to the label's size?" - that will be hardly possible at all, as long as you keep the label out of the normal flow, by positioning it absolute.

"Also, when the li run to the end of the page's width, how can I make it wrap to a new row?" - by not applying white-space: nowrap; to the UL. If you need to specify the white-space behavior so that the text inside your labels doesn't break into multiple lines - then you should apply the white-space property to those labels.

"Rose Pink, Rose Red.. and the rest, should wrap to a new row" there is no Rose Pink etc. as you have posted your code here at present

Yes, there is no Rose Pink, Rose Red... in the HTML, because I omitted those li in the HTML to make it simpler. Rose Pink and etc can be seen in the image capture.

Key here though is the question specifically needs to illustrate the wrap - I assume based upon the container width?  An edit is pending to make a snippet which is a better way to present your problem question here.

Use flexbox and remove all the absolute positioning, it's unnecessary and over-complicating what you are trying to do.


.cable-config span {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #86939e;
}

.cable-choose {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px /* for demo */
}

.cable-choose {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cable-choose li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 15px 5px 0 0;
  height: 40px;
}

.cable-choose input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.cable-choose input[type="radio"]:checked~label {
  background: yellow;
}

.cable-choose label {
  border: 2px solid #e1e8ee;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 90;
}

.cable-choose .sold-out {
  color: #ced3d9;
}

.radio-custom:checked~label {
  border: 2px solid #121b21;
}
<div class="cable-config clearfix">
  <div>
    <h5>Color:</h5>
  </div>

  <ul class="cable-choose">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="black" name="picker" />
      <span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span>
      <label class="" for="black">Black</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="green" name="picker" />
      <span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span>
      <label class="" for="green">Very Long Label Name</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="forest-green" name="picker" /><span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span><label class="" for="forest-green">Forest Green</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" disabled="" id="light-purple" /><span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span><label class="sold-out" for="light-purple">Light Purple</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




Use display: flex for ul styles.


.cable-config span {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #86939E;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cable-choose {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 25px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 5px;
}

.cable-choose li {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

.cable-choose input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.cable-choose input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    background: yellow;  
}

.cable-choose label {
    border: 2px solid #E1E8EE;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 90;
}

.cable-choose .sold-out {
    color: #ced3d9;
}
<div class="cable-config clearfix">
  <div><h5>Color:</h5></div>

  <ul class="cable-choose">
    <li>
      <input
        type="radio" name="cable-color" id="black"
      /><label class="" for="black">Black</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input
        type="radio" name="cable-color" id="forest-green"
      /><label class="" for="forest-green">Forest Green</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input
        type="radio" name="cable-color" id="light-purple"
        disabled=""
      /><label class="sold-out" for="light-purple">Light Purple</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




Your main problem is the fixed width and height used for the list items. Text will simply overflow if it's larger.
There is also no need to use an unordered list for this scenario.
CSS flexbox would definitely be an easier solution as suggested by other members. I have included a working example for you and made some improvements with regard to the custom radio buttons.
Note: "max-width: 600" is only set to demonstrate how the custom radio buttons are wrapped.


.radio-btn {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #E1E8EE;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-btn+.btn:hover {
    border-color: yellow;
}

.radio-btn:checked+.btn {
    background-color: yellow;
    border-color: yellow;
}

.radio-btn:disabled+.btn {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    background-color: #E1E8EE;
    border-color: #E1E8EE;
}

.cable-config {
    max-width: 600;
}
.cable-choose {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cable-choose .btn {
    margin: 5px;
}
<div class="cable-config">

    <h5>Color:</h5>
    
    <div class="cable-choose">
    
        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="cable-options" id="black" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn" for="black">Black</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="cable-options" id="forest-green" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn" for="forest-green">Forest Green</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="cable-options" id="light-purple" autocomplete="off" disabled>
        <label class="btn" for="light-purple">Light Purple</label>
    
        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="cable-options" id="white" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn" for="white">White</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="cable-options" id="velvet-red" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn" for="velvet-red">Velvet Red</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="cable-options" id="ny-pink" autocomplete="off" disabled>
        <label class="btn" for="ny-pink">NY Pink</label>
        
        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="cable-options" id="orange" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn" for="orange">Orange</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="cable-options" id="yellow" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn" for="yellow">Yellow</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="cable-options" id="dark-chocolate" autocomplete="off" disabled>
        <label class="btn" for="dark-chocolate">Dark Chocolate</label>
        
    </div>

</div>




Your code works perfectly here on the above "Run code snippet" window. But, when I tried on my page, everything works well, except that all the inputs are displayed in the normal state. The grey background and strike through don't show on disabled inputs. The yellow also doesn't show when I click. Any idea why?

Use "flex" styles for ul and make it simple


.cable-config span {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #86939E;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cable-choose {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cable-choose {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  gap: 5px;
}

.cable-choose li {
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.cable-choose input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cable-choose input[type="radio"]:checked~label,
.Checked+label {
  background: yellow;
}

.cable-choose label {
  border: 2px solid #E1E8EE;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.cable-choose .sold-out {
  color: #ced3d9;
}
<div class="cable-config clearfix">
  <div>
    <h5>Color:</h5>
  </div>
  <ul class="cable-choose">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" /><span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span><label class="" for="black">Black</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" /><span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span><label class="" for="forest-green">Forest Green</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" disabled="" /><span class="radio-custom-dummy"></span><label class="sold-out" for="light-purple">Light Purple</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
